# Woocommerce - Replacing Variable pricing text through a function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am currently looking to add multiple currencies to be displayed in my variations data. I would like to be able to replace the html generated by available variations function in woocommerce, specifically

```
        'price_html'            => $show_variation_price ? '<span class="price">' . $variation->get_price_html() . '</span>' : '',
```

Ultimately what I am trying to do is pull JSON from a link (Currency exchange rates), parse that JSON into readable code and then have display what is currently displayed (See picture $250.00 in yellow/orange text), along with 2 more currencies which will be calculated off the variation pricing.

Current variations:

[image: Current variations]

Unfortunately after searching for a few hours on here, I have not yet found anything that I can hack together.

Does anyone know what functions would need to be created to simply replace this text and what variables are stored in woocommerce to make it easy to interact with these variation prices?

Thanks!